Existing system follows sum of breaker and new PV system installtion follows 120% rule
We have an existing Main Service Panel (MSP) with a 200A/200A rating, and an existing battery system with a 90A breaker, which follows the Sum of Breakers Rule. I need to install a photovoltaic (PV) system with a 40A breaker. Can I use the 120% rule for the new PV system, given that the existing system follows the Sum of Breakers Rule?

Do you only have one panel?  Is everything feeding into the same panel?  If your loads managed to peak at 270 amps, could it pull 190A from the utility while also pulling 80A from the battery?
